# mongodb, remove one of the replica set's from a sharded cluster

Tags: cluster, mongodb, sharding

I need to remove filed server01 (currently offline for a long time).
The configuration looks like this:

```
shards:
{  "_id" : "mongo1",  "host" : "mongo1/server01:27017,server02:27017,server03:27017" }
{  "_id" : "mongo2",  "host" : "mongo2/server02:27018,server03:27018,server04:27018" }
{  "_id" : "mongo3",  "host" : "mongo3/server03:27019,server04:27019,server05:27019" }
{  "_id" : "mongo4",  "host" : "mongo4/server01:27022,server04:27022,server05:27022" }
{  "_id" : "mongo5",  "host" : "mongo5/server01:27023,server02:27023,server05:27023" }
```

and I have partitioned db's like:

```
{ "_id" : "dbace", "partitioned" : true, "primary" : "mongo2" }
```

etc.

cluster in a production use. It is possible to remove failed server with name 'server01', and how to do it?